# Adding a column that consists of first N letters of other column

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column to my data and I want this column to have first 5 letters of the previous column. Can you guys help me with this?

So better explain it:

I have a data that looks like:

```
a b c 3532121_14231
d g h 1234261_14231
e b n 3346258_14231
a r w 5721345_14231
```

and I want to add 5th column that will have first 5 letters of 4th column

```
a b c 3532121_14231 35321
d g h 1234261_14231 12342
e b n 3346258_14231 33462
a r w 5721345_14231 57213
```

I haven't touched R for long time and confused where to start. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `substr`:

```
within(mydf, {
  V5 = substr(V4, 1, 5)
})
#   V1 V2 V3            V4    V5
# 1  a  b  c 3532121_14231 35321
# 2  d  g  h 1234261_14231 12342
# 3  e  b  n 3346258_14231 33462
# 4  a  r  w 5721345_14231 57213
```